# Best way to convert TensorProto to TensorFlow tensor

Tags: tensorflow

As far as I can tell, there are at least two different ways to recover a Tensor from a TensorProto in Tensorflow 2.3. Say, for the sake of example, that we have

```
tensor = tf.range(10)
tproto = tf.make_tensor_proto(tensor)
```

Then:

- You can use `tf.make_ndarray` like so

`tf.constant(tf.make_ndarray(tproto))`

- Or you can use `tf.io.parse_tensor` like so

`tf.io.parse_tensor(tproto.SerializeToString(), out_type=tf.int32)`

I feel both of these are a bit artificial, since in the former you end up with an intermediate `numpy` array, and in the latter you have to serialize the TensorProto to a string and parse it back. Additionally, `parse_tensor` won't automatically recover the correct data type from the TensorProto. So:

1. Is there a function to do the conversion in a single step? I'd like to see something like `tf.from_tensor_proto` doing the conversion all at once optimizing for speed and memory allocation (or, if `tf.constant(tf.make_ndarray(tproto))` is the best you can do, just wrapping this up).
2. Otherwise, which of the two options above should be preferred (in terms of efficiency, memory usage, etc.)?

Comment: Funny enough, you can just do `tf.constant(tproto)` if you are in graph mode, e.g. within a `@tf.function` (although you cannot pass a `TensorProto` as an argument to a `@tf.function`) or for example like `with tf.Graph().as_default(): t = tf.constant(tproto)` (and they do this in several places within TensorFlow test code). In eager mode it fails, I think in some code that has to figure out the tensor shape. I don't think there is any actual reason it should fail though, maybe it should be reported as a bug.